# Writing a for loop for matrices in MATLAB

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matlab

I am a complete Newbie at MATLAB, and am very confused with the manipulation of matrices using for-loops.

suppose we are given a 6x5 matrix(A), the goal is to write a for loop in MATLAB that can isolate each of the columns of the matrix and then stores that column into a new and empty array(x = []) that I can use later on.

Could someone please help!?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To call one column of a matrix, use `A(:,j)` where `j` is the column number you need (thankfully MATLAB is one-based, meaning arrays begin indexing at the number one). Similarly to call rows use `A(i,:)`.

You really can't loop this well, as far as I know. But, if your loop does do something with the columns independently, then perhaps you need something like this:

```
for j = 1:dim(A, 2) %dim(A, 2) returns the number of columns
    xcol = A(:, j);
    statements
end
```